# How to set a delimiter between each captured packet in tcpdump?

Tags: tcpdump

I would like to pipe the tcpdump output to the stdin of a program of my choice.
But, I don't know what is the delimeter between each packet captured by the tcpdump.
I have gone through the manpage but have not found any setting to set a custom delimiter between each packet.

I would like to have the following format to be piped to the program of my choice:

```
Src_IP_of_Packet, data
```

Where the data is raw (not in ASCII and/or HEX format).
i.e. the `data` that I get using the following command.

```
tcpdump udp port 2112 -i eth0 -s0 -w-
```

With the above command, I am getting only the data but not the source IP.
Moreover, each packet seems to contain a newline character due to which each line is treated to be a new packet by my program because my program by default takes a newline to be the delimiter between each packet.

Answer (score 1):

There is no delimiter and no way to greatly modify the output of `tcpdump` beyond making the output more verbose.  If you are seeking to parse the data, it is best to view each line of text as a single packet, though adding one or more `-v` options will modify that display, resulting in variable numbers of lines for each packet.

If you would like to control which fields in the packet headers are displayed and add/modify delimiters, you will want to either look at `tshark`, which is a part of `Wireshark`, or interact with the packets through a scripting language; in this case, Python using `Scapy` is a great choice.

Comment: So, you mean to say that there is no way to differentiate between each packet in tcpdump?

Comment: But, then it is able to pump the data to a pcap file and Wireshark is able to parse it (i.e. differentiate between each packet in the pcap file). And I suppose, that the data format that tcpdump prints through the command `tcpdump udp port 2112 -i eth0 -s0 -w- ` to stdout is same as to a pcap file. So, if we can know how Wireshark can differentiate, we can as well do the same.

Comment: Could you tell me the command for src_ip,raw_data with tshark? I tried this.. `tshark -f "udp port 2112" -i ens32 -T fields -e ip.src -e data` but it is not printing data!